# How to globally toggle the usage of a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'm looking to create a global toggle variable to turn on and off my decoration depending on the argument passed via the command line.

In the case below, Instead of commenting out the `@time_md5_comparison` when not needed, I want a global toggle depending on the argument passed.

---

**`main.py`**

```
from timing_decorator import time_md5_comparison

@time_md5_comparison
def md5_comparison(a, b):
    if a==b:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

---

**`timing_decorator.py`**

```
def time_md5_comparison(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time()
        print(str(function.__name__) + "  " + str("%.6f "%(t2 - t1)))
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Can I create a variable, say `USE_DECORATOR = True` in the `main.py`, so that the decorator is called and if it's later set to `False`, the original function is called?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Can I create a variable , say USE_DECORATOR = True in the main.py
In that case the decorator is called. If USE_DECORATOR = False the original function is called.

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28654546/4497519 It would be trivial to then toggle using an argument from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators affect the byte-code generated when the function definition following them is executed (which is before and separate from when the compiled function itself runs when it's called). So, short of reloading the whole module with the decorated function in it, probably the only viable approach would be to make the wrapped function execute differently based on the *current* setting of the flag variable.

Note the toggle variable had to be put in a mutable container—a `list`—so that the decorated function would refer to its current value rather than what it was when originally decorated.

---

**`main.py`**

```
from timing_decorator import time_md5_comparison

USE_DECORATOR = [False]

@time_md5_comparison(USE_DECORATOR)
def md5_comparison(a, b):
    if a==b:
        return True
    else:
        return False

md5_comparison(3, 4)  # prints nothing
USE_DECORATOR[0] = True
md5_comparison(5, 6)  # prints timing info
```

Decorators which take arguments other than a single function are essentially ***decorator factories*** which must create and return the actual decorator used. This is why the decorator in your question needed to be nested one level deeper.

---

**`timing_decorator.py`**

```
from functools import wraps
import time

def time_md5_comparison(disabled):
    def decorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if disabled[0]:
                result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                t1 = time.time()
                result = function(*args, **kwargs)
                t2 = time.time()
                print(str(function.__name__)+"  "+ str("%.6f " %(t2 - t1)))
            return result

        return wrapped

    return decorator
```

Comment: I'm still not sure why we use the a mutable container, rather than just a variable. Let me try it out to get a better understanding.

Comment: Took me a little by surprise too, but I believe it's because built-in boolean values like `True` and `False` are immutable, as are strings and integers, so when you pass them to a function their value gets passed, not a reference to them since thay can't be changed. A `list`'s contents _are_ mutable, so they're passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can pass the value in, or simply reset the decorator.

Resetting the decorator would be something like this:

```
import timing_module

if NO_USE_DECORATOR:
    mydecorator = timing_module.empty_decorator
else:
    mydecorator = timing_module.time_md5_comparison


@mydecorator
def myfunc(args):
    pass
```

Obviously, you don't have to call it `mydecorator`. You can reset the `time_md5_comparison` name instead, to point to whatever you like.

Passing the value as an argument puts the logic in the decorator, which is cleaner:

```
#module: timing_module
def original_time_md5_comparison(fn):
    """Original code of your decorator here"""
    # ...
    pass

def no_decorator(fn):
    """Decorator no-op. Just use original function."""
    return fn

def time_md5_comparison(use_decorator = True):
    if use_decorator:
        return original_time_md5_comparison
    else:
        return no_decorator
```