# Python: How to make decorators optional?

Tags: python, python-decorators, optional-parameters

I'm currently running my python code in the terminal with memory_profiler (i.e. python3 -m memory_profiler ./test.py), using the @profile decorator in my code, to allow for memory gathering stats.

However, in order to run my code, I either have to execute the decorator each time or comment out the decorator and run the code normally.

If I run the code normally in my terminal with the @profile decorator included, the terminal will output the following: "NameError: name 'profile' is not defined".

Is it possible to keep the @profile decorator in my code as an optional component, therefore allowing me to run the code normally and only implement the decorator when adding the memory_profiler?

Comment: Create a new director that checks a global flag to decide whether to call `profile`, or when you're not profiling, replace `profile` with a simple call to the original function.

Comment: Maybe this post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636350/toggling-decorators